# definition of the \bibcite command

Tags: bibliographies

in an .aux file, the following `\bibcite` command appears:

```
\bibcite{reference key}{Keypart on line 1,\newline Keypart on line 2}
```

This was obtained by writing the following entry in the bibliography environment:

```
\bibitem[Keypart on line 1,\newline %
Keypart on line 2]{reference key}
  \textit{Title}.
```

The purpose is twofold:

1. In the text (where the corresponding `\cite` command appears), the following should be displayed:

   > ............................................................................. [Keypart on line 1,
   >   Keypart on line 2]
2. In the bibliography itself, the following should be displayed:

   > [Keypart on line 1
   >   Keypart on line 2] Title.

All 2 cases do NOT happen. 3 questions on this:

1. Where is `\bibcite` defined?
2. Why is the `\newline` not working?
3. What can be done about this? Is it possible too redefine `\bibcite` with a `\renewcommand`, so that the `\newline` works? I think, I say think, that the `\bibcite` command uses some kind of `\mbox` structure, cancelling the \newline.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \begin{document}


   \noindent ------------------------------
   ------------------------------‌​-----------
   ---------‌​--------------------‌​-----------------

   \bigskip
    \noindent Veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery    long text line 1 \cite{ReferenceKey}
   text line 2.

   \begin{thebibliography}{ReferenceKey}
   \bibitem[Keypart on line 1,\newline % 
   Keypart on line 2]{ReferenceKey} Displayed bibliographic entry\ldots
   \end{thebibliography}
   \end{document}
   ```

Regards,
Francky

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  please provide a small compilable example that produces the (nonworking) result.  this should start with `\documentclass`, load only the relevant packages, and end with `\end{document}`.  without knowing more about your present setup, anything we could tell you would be just a guess.

Comment: Ok, here we go \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\bigskip
\noindent
Veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery long text line 1 \cite{ReferenceKey} 
text line 2.


\begin{thebibliography}{ReferenceKey}

   \bibitem[Keypart on line 1,\newline %
            Keypart on line 2]{ReferenceKey}
     Displayed bibliographic entry\ldots

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
Noting, but really nothing is correct about this.

Comment: as you see code in comments doesn't work, you can edit the question and use a code section (`{}` button) so line endings preserved

Comment: forcing a line ending here is really really odd, the `\cite` can come anywhere in a line :-) the problem you are having is not with `\bibcite` it is with `\cite` which boxes its output.

Answer (score 2):

The layout here looks very strange but...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\@cite@ofmt\@firstofone
\def\@biblabel#1{[\def\newline{\\}\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}]}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent ------------------------------
------------------------------‌​-----------
---------‌​--------------------‌​-----------------

\bigskip
 \noindent Veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery long text line 1 \cite{ReferenceKey}
text line 2.

\begin{thebibliography}{ReferenceKey}
\bibitem[Keypart on line 1,\newline % 
Keypart on line 2]{ReferenceKey} Displayed bibliographic entry\ldots
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\@cite@ofmt\@firstofone
\def\@biblabel#1{[\def\newline{\\}\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}]}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent ------------------------------
------------------------------‌​-----------
---------‌​--------------------‌​-----------------

\bigskip
 \noindent Veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery long text line 1 \cite{ReferenceKey}
text line 2.

\begin{thebibliography}{ReferenceKey}
\bibitem[Keypart on line 1,\newline % 
Keypart on line 2]{ReferenceKey} Displayed bibliographic entry\ldots
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

or moving the bracket as

```
\def\@biblabel#1{\def\newline{\\}\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}[#1]\end{tabular}}
```

[image]

Comment: I understand how the biblabel thing works. Smart construction. I don't understand how the cite command is redefined. Can someone explain how this redefinition works? What is ofm and what is firstofone?

Comment: I want to make the biblabel beter. This is what I try:

    \makeatletter 
      \let\@cite@ofmt\@firstofone 
      \def\@biblabel#1{[\def\newline{\\}
                        $ \[ \mbox{ \begin{tabular}[t]
                                     {@{}l@{}}#1
                                    \end{tabular}
                              }
                          \]
                        $
                       ]
                      }
    \makeatother 

For some reason. pdfLaTeX crahes on this. Why?

Comment: Surf to http://www.Leyn.eu/code.jpg, in order to see the above code properly. My apologies for the mess.